# Palindrome algorithm in Scialb

Tags: scilab

Could you help me to construct an algorithm in Scilab that searches for the longest palindrome in a zero-one sequence of n - elements.
The output should be given the length of the palindrome and position in the string starting the searched sequence.

Example: for 111010101100, the longest palindrome is 110101011. The length of the palindrome is 9, and the position in the string starting the sequence is 2.

Comment: You need an algorithm first, regardless the language for implementing it: take a look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/manachers-algorithm-linear-time-longest-palindromic-substring-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible implementation (for n>1) of the algorithm proposed in the comment above:

```
x = "10100111000";
n = length(x);
lgmax = 0;
pos = 0;

for i = 1:n-1
    // k=0: odd sequence, k=1: even sequence
    for k = 0:1
        j=1;
        while j <= min(i-1+k,n-i) && part(x,i+j) == part(x,i-j+k)
            j = j+1;
        end
        if 2*j-1-k > lgmax
            lgmax = 2*j-1-k;
            pos = i-j+1+k;
        end
     end
 end

 disp(part(x,pos:pos+lgmax-1))
```